# How can I configure Mac Terminal to have color ls output?

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I configure Mac Terminal to have color ls output?
I am using MacOS 10.5

Comment: This is a great question...  I've always expected ls --color (a la gnu ls) to just work everywhere.  MacOS doesn't accept --color, so I assumed that it didn't have colored output as an option at all.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-osx-terminal-color-ls-output-option/

Answer (score 443):

Edit:

```
~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
~/.profile
```

and add the following line to simply enable color output via `ls`:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

To customize the coloring shown by `ls` you can optionally add this variable, `LSCOLORS`.

#### Examples

- Default

  ```
  export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
  ```
- You can use this if you are using a **black background**

  ```
  export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
  ```
- If you'd like to mimic the colors of a typical Linux terminal:

  ```
  export LSCOLORS=ExGxBxDxCxEgEdxbxgxcxd
  ```

Once you've add the above to either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` you can either logout/login or source the file in your shell, for eg:

```
$ . ~/.bash_profile
```

**NOTE:** If you need help in selecting colors to use you can use this online tool called [LSCOLORS Generator](https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/).

Comment: Is there a way to make the colored text not look bold?

Comment: I found this (and up-voted it) in July 2015, when running Mavericks.  Now on El Capitan (using the same `.profile` file, it no longer works.  I can check the values using `echo $LSCOLORS $CLICOLOR` and they are as defined but it no longer works.  Any reason this would be the case?

Comment: @JamieCook I find Mikulas' colors more linux consistent. Specifically, a broken symlink should be dark red. With your lscolors its blue... this is not a small issue.

Comment: Does not work on mac sierra and later

Comment: @RayFoss indeed, that is no small issue, but OS X cannot make a difference between valid and broken symlinks by default. The only viable alternative is to [use gnu ls](https://superuser.com/a/725392/264813)

Comment: @StevieG Works for me on High Sierra. Make sure you set it right: `echo $CLICOLOR` should give 1?

Comment: The default on Mac is actually `LSCOLORS=exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad ` Source: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ls

Comment: Note that `.zprofile` can be used for the same two lines, if you are using `zsh`.

Answer (score 201):

You can add

```
alias ls='ls -G'
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` to get colored `ls` output.

Comment: Mine is alias ls="ls -Gp" — the -p adds a slash after each directory. For me, it provides that much more visual differentiation, which is helpful.

Comment: I see your `-p` and raise you a `-F` which in addition puts an `*` after executables, `|` after pipes, `@` after symlinks, et cetera.

Comment: Just for fun, throw in a -h, which will format sizes in "human readable" units, i.e.  100b  10k,  23m, 4.2g

Comment: If you don't have a .bash_profile already at ~/.bash_profile, be sure to source it, so that it will work.  Do this with "source ~/.bash_profile"

Comment: Dunno if this has changed since 2011, but you can replace the alias with `export CLICOLOR=1` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: For the record, I usually prefer *not* to `alias` `ls`, because 1) If you actually memorize the command line parameters (which aren't that difficult to remember and type out), you'll be able to achieve the same behavior and output on multiple systems where you don't maintain an updated personal `.bash_profile`, and 2) because many times I like to pipe my `ls` output to other commands in order to execute operations on files/directories in the output, which always fails if there is a `*` or a `@` included in the filenames (without first piping to `tr` or `sed` to remove the unwanted characters).

Comment: ok. then i advise to put  `-t` to sort by date

Answer (score 38):

I find that all I need really is adding this to my `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` (for Bash) or `~/.zshrc` (for Zsh, the new default shell in Catalina)

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

Comment: Or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: doesn't appear to work on capitan ):

Comment: Worked like a boss in El Captian for me, thanks for posting @Filype

Comment: You have to either: 1. close you terminal and reopen, 2. resource the config file: `. ~/.bash_profile`,  or 3. logout/login

Answer (score 13):

If you want a readable Mac OS X Terminal color scheme, you may want to look into this:

- <s>http://toddwerth.com/2008/01/25/a-black-os-x-leopard-terminal-theme-that-is-actually-readable/</s>
- <s>http://toddwerth.com/2011/07/21/the-original-ir_black-for-os-x-lion/</s>

I've been using this for over a year now, and I might not be able to function without it!

Here's an updated link:

- https://github.com/justincase/IR_Black-OSX

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal allows customizing the ANSI colors, so using SIMBL or other extensions is no longer necessary. It also supports 256 colors.

Answer (score 12):

Also you can customize the prompt color (and its format) by adding:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;33m\]\h:\W \u\$\[\e[m\] '
```

to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` file. Where `0;33` is regular yellow which looks nice in my black/semitransparent terminal window.

Here is a full list of colors and their explanations: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt

[image: My awesome terminal window]

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I'm using [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) for adding color and other tricks to my Terminal. I think that is the easiest way.

> oh-my-zsh is an open source, community-driven framework for managing
>   your Zsh configuration.
>
> It comes bundled with a ton of helpful functions, helpers, plugins,
>   themes, and a few things that make you shout…

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful color theme. Can I use this color theme on my bash?

Comment: Hmm you should probably look at `oh-my-bash`

Comment: Super late to the party... but do you happen to recall what theme is being used in your screenshot?

Comment: @EricHarlan you got all the theme there https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use the GNU `ls` which is part of the 'coreutils' program.

You can get it via [Rudix](http://code.google.com/p/rudix/downloads/list?can=2&q=coreutils) or Homebrew (`brew info coreutils`)or Macports or Fink. That might be preferable to using a "Mac OS X-only" solution if you use the same shell config files on different systems, or are already familiar with GNU ls.

Comment: https://github.com/gibbling/dircolors

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: I switched to [Oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) a year back and it is awesome. My favourite theme is [lambda-mod](https://github.com/halfo/lambda-mod-zsh-theme) and [my version](https://github.com/sandjaie/zsh-lambda-modified) of it. 

Combining all the answers here is what I use:

```
COLOR_RED="\033[0;31m"
COLOR_YELLOW="\033[0;33m"
COLOR_GREEN="\033[0;32m"
COLOR_OCHRE="\033[38;5;95m"
COLOR_BLUE="\033[0;34m"
COLOR_WHITE="\033[0;37m"
COLOR_RESET="\033[0m"

#git_color
function git_color {
  local git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"

  if [[ ! $git_status =~ "working directory clean" ]]; then
    echo -e $COLOR_RED
  elif [[ $git_status =~ "Your branch is ahead of" ]]; then
    echo -e $COLOR_YELLOW
  elif [[ $git_status =~ "nothing to commit" ]]; then
    echo -e $COLOR_GREEN
  else
    echo -e $COLOR_OCHRE
  fi
}

#git_branch
function git_branch {
  local git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
  local on_branch="On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
  local on_commit="HEAD detached at ([^${IFS}]*)"

  if [[ $git_status =~ $on_branch ]]; then
    local branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "($branch)"
  elif [[ $git_status =~ $on_commit ]]; then
    local commit=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "($commit)"
  fi
}

PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]'
PS1+="\[\$(git_color)\]"        # colors git status
PS1+="\$(git_branch)"           # prints current branch
PS1+="\[$COLOR_BLUE\]\[$COLOR_RESET\]\$ "
export PS1

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
alias ls="ls -Gp"
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Forget all those decades-old cryptic codes for gosh sakes, use the built in Terminal --> Preferences... Settings pane to set the default skin, and edit the ANSI colors to your liking. You can set the font, too. I prefer Menlo 12pt. This is how any regular Joe can do it, and avoid all the crazy command-line, unix-esque way of doing things as other posters have suggested.

Comment: I think anybody experienced enough to even know that `ls` can have colored output is also able to run a few Unix commands to configure it correctly.

Comment: But this just makes ls show in one colour it does not make links, directories, files show in different colours as ls can do

Answer (score 4):

**Simply** add the following line to `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export PS1=" \[\033[34m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[31m\]\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

**Preview:**
[image]

This is my preferred colors. You can customize each part of prompt's color by changing `m` codes (e.g. `34m`) which are ANSI color codes.

**List of ANSI Color codes:**

- Black: 30m
- Red: 31m
- Green: 32m
- Yellow: 33m
- Blue: 34m
- Purple: 35m
- Cyan: 36m
- White: 37m

Answer (score 4):

For the Catalina version, you need to add `export CLICOLOR=1` in `~/.zshrc`.

If you want to adjust the colour palette, change colours theme in terminal settings.

Comment: this is the most up to date answer for Catalina with zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely nothing worked for me.
Eventually I found a very weird solution that fixed everything.

I opened `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` and searched for 'terminal' with Ctrl+F. I removed a section, that said 'DisableColor' or something like that.

Comment: `plist` is a binary format in MacOS 13.1, not meant for human eyes.

Comment: Problem is fixed and Mac still works, so I don't care.

Comment: For those who do care, VS Code has extensions to read `plist` files.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal **Settings** -> **Profiles** -> **Shell**

Check **Run command:** and enter `export CLICOLOR=1`

[image]