# How do I run VI with colors on Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal, color, vi

I'm looking to enable color syntax highlighting in vi. I just enabled colors in Terminal via [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/how-can-i-configure-mac-terminal-to-have-color-ls-output). Any ideas on how to enable this?

NOTE: Usually on Linux when I open vi with `vi file.txt` and it opens in black and white on default, I can open the same file with `vim file.txt` and it will show the colors, but this does not work here.

Comment: For color highlighting in general e.g. from `ls` or `grep`, see [ansi-color-codes-in-vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592715/ansi-color-codes-in-vim/41041751#41041751) on SO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It’s a matter of having the right settings in your `~/.vimrc` file. Here’s mine: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc.

The key is to add this:

```
" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax on
```

You can install color schemes in your `~/.vim/colors` directory. To enable a colorscheme, use:

```
" Select a colorscheme
colorscheme molokai
```

I’m using [Molokai](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/colors/molokai.vim), which looks like this when editing a JavaScript file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! EDIT: On a side note, adding `colorsheme molokai` yielded `E185: Cannot find color scheme molokai`. But the syntax part still worked! :)

Comment: @gusterlover6 Yeah, as I explained in my post you need to have the Molokai colorscheme installed in `~/.vim/colors/molokai.vim`. You can download it from the link in my answer. Enjoy!

Comment: If you use [Janus](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46633/292) you get easy access to colour schemes (and plugins).

Answer (score 5):

I'll also say that MacVim is a nice upgrade from the standard Vim that ships with OS X, but it isn't necessary. What you need is Vim configuration that adds syntax highlighting to VIM.

The fastest way to get that is with [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) -- it's a set of VIM plugins and configuration files pre-configured and ready to go. It works with Vim and MacVim.

To install it:

```
curl -Lo- http://bit.ly/janus-bootstrap | bash
```

And then follow the instructions. That calls their [automatic installer](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/bootstrap.sh). It requires Vim 7.3 or greater. You'll get an easy path to colours and plugins in Vim.

[image: Vim with Janus]

Comment: @denis yes, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to customize your ~/.vimrc to enable syntax highlighting, among other things.  Very simplistically, you'll want to add:

```
syntax on
```

Google "vimrc" for sample vim configuration files.

Comment: It drives me mad when people say to "google stuff" in a stackexchange answer - how do you think folks got to the question in the first place?!